# To output the closing price, total dividends of each year from a time-series dataframe

Tags: pandas, datetime, time-series, stock

My dataframe look like this:

```py
            Open   High    Low  Close    Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits
Date                                                                     
2015-08-07  16.64  16.64  16.64  16.64         0        0.0             0
2015-08-11  16.51  16.59  16.14  16.16  11408900        0.0             0
2015-08-12  15.88  15.88  15.16  15.27  24258500        0.0             0
2015-08-13  15.33  15.69  15.33  15.58   8237600        0.0             0
2015-08-14  15.59  15.83  15.59  15.78   4399600        0.0             0
...           ...    ...    ...    ...       ...        ...           ...

2020-08-03  19.75  19.75  19.45  19.45   7352600        0.0             0
2020-08-04  19.70  19.99  19.64  19.69   4250500        0.0             0
2020-08-05  19.87  19.98  19.59  19.83   3414080        0.0             0
2020-08-06  20.11  20.56  20.02  20.40   6128100        0.0             0
2020-08-07  20.52  20.69  20.40  20.60   8295000        0.0             0
```

I like to select the closing price of each year and also calculate the average "Volume" and Total Dividends for the year.

The output to like this:

```py
2015  20.52... 

2016  21.53...

2017  25.33...

....
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple case of use `resample()` then define which aggregates you want from the columns.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
end=dt.datetime.today()
start=end-dt.timedelta(59)
tickers=['WBA']

df = yf.download(tickers,group_by=tickers,start=start,end=end,interval='5m')
print(df.resample("Y").agg({"Volume":"mean","Close":"last"}).to_string())
```

**output**

```
                                Volume  Close
Datetime                                     
2020-12-31 00:00:00-05:00  72404.45197  41.52
```